# How to get the position of character at onTouch in editext

Tags: android

i want to get the Position of the character at the time of touch on the editext box in my application with the help of the coordinates of Ontouch. How should this be possible .
Please help me 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I've written a method to do just that. It's for TextView, but should work for EditText since it extends TextView. Make a custom EditText and stick this method in there.

**NOTE** x and y are the getX() and getY() component of the MotionEvent during OnTouch

```
    public int getCharIndexFromCoordinate( int x, int y ) {

    // Offset the top padding
    int height = getPaddingTop();

    for (int i = 0; i < getLayout().getLineCount(); i++) {

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        getLayout().getLineBounds( i, bounds );
        height += bounds.height();

        if ( height >= y ) {

            int lineStart = getLayout().getLineStart( i );
            int lineEnd = getLayout().getLineEnd( i );

            Spanned span = (Spanned) getText();
            RelativeSizeSpan[] sizeSpans = span.getSpans( lineStart, lineEnd, RelativeSizeSpan.class );
            float scaleFactor = 1;
            if ( sizeSpans != null ) {
                for (int j = 0; j < sizeSpans.length; j++) {
                    scaleFactor = sizeSpans[j].getSizeChange();
                }
            }

            String lineSpan = getText().subSequence( lineStart, lineEnd ).toString();
            float[] widths = new float[lineSpan.length()];
            TextPaint paint = getPaint();
            paint.getTextWidths( lineSpan, widths );

            float width = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < lineSpan.length(); j++) {

                width += widths[j] * scaleFactor;

                if ( width >= x || j == lineSpan.length() - 1 ) {

                    return lineStart + j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```